# Как правильно настроить criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Есть 2 сущности связанные многие-ко-многим.
Если я хочу получить все данные то
`result = session.createCriteria(ProductBrand.class).list();`
вываливает мне по 4 дубля(рис. 1) из-за связи многие-ко-многим.
А SQL-запрос
`result = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM wk_cas_product_brand")
                    .addEntity(ProductBrand.class).list();`
работает то нормально(никаких дублей из-за связи нет(рис. 2)), но напрягает, что в нем нужно писать реальное название таблицы.
Можно ли и как настроить ограничения в критерии, дабы связь многие-ко-многим не учитывалась?

---

рис. 1
[image: не правильно]

---

рис. 2
[image: правильно]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй `Projections.distinct`

```
session.createCriteria(ProductBrand.class).setProjection(
    Projections.distinct(Projections.projectionList()
            .add(Projections.property("Марка"), "Марка")))
    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(ProductBrand.class))
    .list();
```

Где *Марка* это имя поля из класса **ProductBrand**

Comment: Чертовщина, вылетает с NullPointerException... не могу понять, почему не работает, если всё верно.

Comment: @Артём-.....-...-.- покажи лог ощибки

Comment: а, не. Это я тупанул, забыл поле id в Projections.property указать...